# Why do my menu items activate a scroll function?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, menu, navigation

I used the 'Page scroll to id' plugin for Wordpress to set up a one scroll page where the menu items let you scroll through the section. I noticed the animation wasn't working, which had been the case for a few other websites I worked on in the past. Strange enough, unchecking the option 'activate on menu-items' did the trick back then and made the animation work. However, this time is different. I checked the general forum for this plugin on Wordpress.org to troubleshoot this and I later deactivated the plugin to try to make it work with a simple jQuery function.

After those attemps I noticed that the menu items were still letting me scroll through the page, even though I removed my function and deactivated the plugin. I cleared my browser cache and installed WP Super Cache to delete any cache from the website itself. Neither of these did the trick.

I have no idea what makes the menu items scroll through the page, but it overrides any workaround I attempted to get an animated scroll function. There aren't any plugins installed at this moment. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

**Edit:**
I tried a couple of things:

- I replaced the id's and urls of the menu items with something I didn't use before, but the buttons still made me jump, just to be sure it's no caching
- After that, I checked the database, but couldn't find anything related
- I did a complete reinstall of WordPress and the database, but left my own parent and child theme of twentysixteen in, the problem remained
- I downloaded a clean twentysixteen and replaced the parent theme with it, the problem remained
- Checked all files from the child theme just to be sure, but there's nothing that could cause this

This makes me think there now is a jump/scroll function in either the parent theme or the WP installation itself, which is weird because this shouldn't be standard. (let alone impossible to override)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The line "get_footer();" wasn't there in the front-page.php, which is the obvious reason that no function in the footer worked. But it was also conflicting with the animation of the Page Scroll To ID plugin, which is very unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Could be still stetting #id in the menu, try to check the Menu inside appearance.

Other things you can do it's delete the tables of the plug-in in the DB.
when you uninstall the plug-in form wp, the tables in the db still exits, it's difficult but cold be that.

Also you can check if you have really delete all the jQuery script from all files and founder.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, do you mean the animated scroll on click, or the jump on click? I get a jump because of your anchor links in your nav, but I'm not getting an animated scroll (like a smooth scroll effect) over here.

Comment: I do mean the jump. The problem is that I don't know where it's coming from and I'm unable to override it with something that does have an animation

Comment: Oh, the jump is just standard browser practice - if I remember correctly (looks like you removed the link to the project), your anchor link has an id of #foo, and it's jumping to a div with an id of #foo. If you're unable to override it with something like SmoothScroll.js, that would indicate a problem with implementing that plugin or other Javascript functionality.